# Can my Modem Ethernet split for two routers?

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I have 2 routers and the modem supplied by Comcast. I have metal beams in my floor that seem to limit my wireless signal, so I thought I could use a second router on the second floor.

I bought a Gigaware Splitter/Combiner. The modem has only 1 ethernet port. I thought I could use the splitter to branch off to each router, but it does not work, only one router is available at a time, or so it seems.

I cannot see how the combiner works, since I just want to take the signal from my modem and then split it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically the cable or DSL modem allows only one device to be connected (because it supplies only one IP address).  You should instead connect one of the wireless/routers to the other: from the one that has is by the modem run the ethernet from one of its LAN ports to the WAN (internet) port of the second router.

Comment: Thank you for you immediate response. I was unaware that one router can be plugged into another.

Comment: They provision for only one modem MAC per account.

Comment: Thank you mgkrebbs.The advice seems to have worked. It appears I can log into either router.

Comment: Thanks to mgkrebbs. It is possible to plug a router into another router. I wish I knew that a few weeks ago instead of trying to figure out why the ethernet splitter was not actually splitting. Seems to work well now, Both routers have a good signal. Was it that easy? Now, I can position my 2 routers strategically to get good wi-fi throughout my home. Thanks again, Bob